# Not able to download react

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs, path, node-modules

I get the following error while trying to download react.

C:\Users\Navya\Coding\AIproject>npx create-react-app my-app
'npx' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I have the latest version of node.js downloaded and I also have set it in my path in system variables as C:\Program Files\nodejs.

I had the same problem trying to use pip or the PIL library for python. If i try to use any command it says it is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I tried to reinstall every program and set up paths, nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open cmd in your system and try entering command node --version. If nothing comes try reinstalling. And remember always try to use node LTS version which is currently 18.17.0.